# search in txt file python

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

I've been working on this code for days, but no result. The function `autodecrypt` takes a string encyrpted by `encrypt` whose characters in the domain A-Z and a-z are changed by a number `offset`. So in ASCII code 'A' would be 65 and if `offset` = 7 then 'A' is now 'H' (whose code # is 72). Offset values from 0-95 will be tried. The decryption will be checked if 85% or more of the words appear in a txt file called `dictionary.txt` which basically contains a bunch of common words. This is where my problem lies: it is not checking properly if the strings I generated are in the txt file.

```
def autodecrypt(ciphertext):
    text = list(ciphertext)
    t = open ('dictionary.txt', 'r')
    m = t.read()
    diccond = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' #initializing variables
    ntext = []
    ctext = ''
    i = 0
    offset = 0
    check = 0
    while offset <= 95:                   #cycling through 95 offset values
        while i < len(text):              #decrypting ciphertext with given offset value
            r = ord(text[i])
            if r - offset < 32:
                s = chr(127 - (offset - (r - 32)))
            else:
                s = chr(r - offset)
            ntext.append(s)
            i+=1
        stext = ''.join(ntext) #make decrypted list (ntext) into string, stext
        for j in stext:       #removing punctuation and store in new string, ctext
            if j in diccond:
                ctext += j
        cltext = ctext.lower() #lowercasing ctext string
        for k in (cltext.split(' ')):  #checking if ctext, list version, is in txt file
            if k in m:
                check +=1
        if check / len(ctext.split(' ')) >= 0.85: #checking if 85% or over of ctext string version in txt file
            return stext
        else:                            #else if there is not any fail and return cipher text (see below)
            fail = 0
        check = 0 #resetting all variables 
        ctext = ''
        ntext=[]  
        i=0
        offset +=1 #increasing offset
    if fail == 0:
        return ciphertext
```

Also if there is not 85% or more match, then the original encrypted string is returned.

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are using `m = t.read()` in a loop (inside another loop) but, after the first iteration, `t.read()` will return an empty string. You should just read the file at the beginning and use the result. That's the cleanest approach. Also, you should probably put the words in your dictionary in a `set`, so it isn't painfully slow.

Comment: Yeah I edited that after posting, however it still does not work. Specifically for this test case where the original text is `'Je pense, donc, je suis.'` and the encrypted text is `'Wr-}r{!r9-q|{p9-wr-!#v!;'`. The words in the original text are not in the txt file so it should return the encrypted text, though it returns `'f"<-"+0"H<!,+ H<\'"<02&0J'`

Comment: When running your code with  
ciphertext = 'Wr-}r{!r9-q|{p9-wr-!#v!;' and an empty dictionary.txt itreturns the correct result as 'Wr-}r{!r9-q|{p9-wr-!#v!;'.
Some more specific data for testing would be helpful.  
When you try to find 'je' in your dictionary file and it contains a word like 'meje' that will be a hit.

Comment: What does "it's not checking properly" mean? What behavior do you observe? Are there exceptions or just bad output? What is the bad output and how did it differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Python 2.x (you need to tag more specifically!), the problem appears to be here: `check / len(ctext.split(' '))`  That's an integer division, with 0 and 1 being the only possible results (and it can only be 1 if every single word was in the file).  To get a floating-point result, you need to convert at least one operand to float before the division:  `float(check) / len(ctext.split(' '))` perhaps.